# Is there a way to update Bitbucket plugin without restarting Bitbucket?

Tags: java, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I want to make changes to Bitbucket Server Repository Hook for Mirroring (https://github.com/ef-labs/stash-hook-mirror), then remove original and install the updated version.

However, after making such change, Bitbucket starts giving `java.lang.ClassCastException` errors with a stacktrace like this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.englishtown.bitbucket.hook.MirrorRequest cannot be cast to com.englishtown.bitbucket.hook.MirrorRequest
        at com.atlassian.stash.internal.concurrent.HazelcastBucketedExecutor.schedule(HazelcastBucketedExecutor.java:63)
        at com.atlassian.stash.internal.concurrent.DelegatingInternalBucketedExecutor.schedule(DelegatingInternalBucketedExecutor.java:24)
        at com.englishtown.bitbucket.hook.MirrorRepositoryHook.lambda$schedulePushes$0(MirrorRepositoryHook.java:177)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at com.englishtown.bitbucket.hook.MirrorRepositoryHook.schedulePushes(MirrorRepositoryHook.java:177)
        at com.englishtown.bitbucket.hook.MirrorRepositoryHook.validate(MirrorRepositoryHook.java:138)
        at com.atlassian.stash.internal.hook.repository.DefaultRepositoryHookService.validateSettings(DefaultRepositoryHookService.java:896)
        at com.atlassian.stash.internal.hook.repository.DefaultRepositoryHookService.lambda$enable$0(DefaultRepositoryHookService.java:203)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
```

Seems that BitBucket caches data from the plugin and does not purge it after plugin removal. This is a common problem with it - see those tickets: https://github.com/ef-labs/stash-hook-mirror/issues/84 or https://github.com/ef-labs/stash-hook-mirror/issues/83

Suggested workaround there is to restart BitBucket instance, and it works.

Another workaround that seems to work is renaming classes and files to include a version as suffix: like `MirrorRepositoryHook.java` to `MirrorRepositoryHookV331.java`.

Is there more elegant solution?